# PDO error code HY093, yet number of bound variables does match the number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following php function and have checked it over countless times.

I have looked at about 30 different questions abouts the HY903 error code. However, none of them seem to apply.

I have checked the number of columns, with the number of placeholders, I have checked that the spelling is consistent. I have even enclosed values that could be null in if(!is_null){} but nothing seems to shift this error. I have to be missing something small, but I can't for the life of me find out what it is.

```
function add_page($title, $linkStub, $content,$gitTitle,$buttonLabel,$buttonLink,$buttonText,$buttonTarget)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `pages`(
            `pageId`,
            `title`,
            `linkStub`,
            `content`,
            `gitTitle`,
            `buttonLabel`,
            `buttonLink`,
            `buttonText`,
            `buttonTarget`
            )
            VALUES (
            NULL ,
            :title ,
            :linkStub ,
            :content ,
            :gitTitle ,
            :buttonLabel ,
            :buttonLink,
            :buttonText,
            :buttonTarget
            )";

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':linkStub', $linkStub, PDO::PARAM_STR, 150);
    $stmt->bindParam(':content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if(!is_null($gitTitle))
    {
        $stmt->bindParam(':gitTitle', $gitTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR, 150);
    }
    if(!is_null($buttonLink))
    {
        $stmt->bindParam(':buttonLabel', $buttonLabel, PDO::PARAM_STR, 150);
        $stmt->bindParam(':buttonLink',  $buttonLink, PDO::PARAM_STR, 150);
        $stmt->bindParam(':buttonText', $buttonText, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
        $stmt->bindParam(':buttonTarget', $buttonTarget, PDO::PARAM_INT, 2);
    }
    $bool = $stmt->execute();
    print_pre($stmt->errorInfo()); //Uncomment for error reporting
    return $bool;
}
```

EDIT:

This question is not a duplicate of the ones you marked these issues there were incorrect amount of bindings, this is dealing with NULL values which Robbie Averill kindly pointed out.

Comment: so, if $gitTitle or $buttonlink are null there wil be fewer bound params....

Comment: Yeah Robbie Averill point out the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only bind some of the parameters if their values aren't null. You should handle your errors before you execute the statement, rather than executing anyway, or just bind null.

PDO won't execute successfully with unbound parameters, so that is likely why you are getting that error.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is did it, I originally have the else statement in which would just bind like this 

else
        {
            $stmt->bindParam(':gitTitle', $gitTitle);
        }

However, I think at the time I had a typo so overlooked this as the problem.

Thanks for your help